# Non-reply from server in c++ with Windows, TCP (RFC 2229)

Tags: c++, sockets, window, client-server, recv

I am making a socket programming code

which send a socket and receive from the server. ([www.dict.org](http://www.dict.org))

I could connect the server using connect and send()
(The server requires one send to connect)

After the connection, I sent a char array as a command, but the server does not send anything.

I cited part 2.3 and 8 of RFC 2229 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2229)

and I sent a char array as "HELP" or "DEFINE ! ONE".

A few times the server sent me a message as your order is wrong.

But now I cannot get a message like that.

````cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")


void print_array(char x[]);
int count_array(char x[]);

int main()
{
    int iResult;
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET Client_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in Sock_info;

    char message[512];   // recv function's result will be saved.
                         //Command lines MUST NOT exceed 1024 characters in length (Part 2.3 RFC 2229)


    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        cout << "WSAStartup failed with error" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return FALSE;
    }

    Client_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (Client_sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Failed to create a socket" << endl;
        closesocket(Client_sock);
        return FALSE;
    }

    int nTime = 10000; //10 Sec stopwatch
    if (setsockopt(Client_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&nTime, sizeof(nTime)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        shutdown(Client_sock, SD_RECEIVE | SD_SEND);
        closesocket(Client_sock);
        cout << "Waiting" << endl;
        cout << "10 Secs over.";
        system("pause");
        return FALSE;
    }

    memset(&Sock_info, 0, sizeof(Sock_info));// Address structure clear
    Sock_info.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Sock_info.sin_port = htons(2628);// Get port
    InetPton(AF_INET, "216.18.20.172", &Sock_info.sin_addr.s_addr);  //IP of dict.org

    if (connect(Client_sock, (SOCKADDR*)&Sock_info, sizeof(Sock_info)) == SOCKET_ERROR) // The fail of request to connect the server
    {
        closesocket(Client_sock);
        return FALSE;
    }

    //Connect using text capabilities msg-id for code 220 in part 3.1 RFC 2229
    if (send(Client_sock, "[ client initiates connection ]", 512, 0) < 0)
    {
        closesocket(Client_sock);
        return FALSE;
    }
    
    if (recv(Client_sock, message, 512, 0) < 0)
    {
        closesocket(Client_sock);
        return FALSE;
    }


    cout << "Send Help" << endl;
    char request[] = "<HELP>";
    iResult = send(Client_sock, request, sizeof(request), 0);
    if (iResult < 0)
    {
        cout << "Failed to send a request" << endl;
        system("pause");
        closesocket(Client_sock);
        return FALSE;
    }
    cout << "SENT" << endl;
    while (iResult > 0)
    {
        iResult = recv(Client_sock, message, 512, 0);
        cout << "RECEIVed" << endl;
        if (iResult < 0)
        {
            cout << "Failed to receive a message" << endl;
            system("pause");
            closesocket(Client_sock);
            return FALSE;
        }
        print_array(message);
    }
    print_array(message);
    // Print the information
    int count = 0;


    //4. Close socket
    closesocket(Client_sock);
    //5. Quit winsock

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}

int count_array(char x[])
{
    int cnt;
    cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; x[i] != '\n'; i++)
    {
        cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}
void print_array(char x[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count_array(x); i++)
    {
        cout << x[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```
````

Comment: Where are you running this program? How did you build it? How did you deploy it? Which is the client and which is the server? How does each program know what it is? What is the network layout like? Are there firewalls? Where is the full program that compiles? Provide a [MCVE] with all necessary details to reproduce.

Comment: Note: in `send(Client_sock, "[ client initiates connection ]", 512, 0)` the number of bytes to send, 512,  VASTLY exceeds the size of the message. `send` will dutifully try to send 512 bytes and march off the end of the message into the great unknown. This will result in the dreaded [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) where anything could happen. Maybe even the error you're trying to sort out.

Comment: Also note that when you `recv(Client_sock, message, 512, 0)` you MUST keep the return value. It tells you how many bytes up to the requested maximum of 512 were read from the socket. You could get as little as 1 byte.

Comment: Oh it was the problem of the size! thank you